# Apache 2.4 don't follow all symlinks

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, symbolic-link

I'm configuring my local Apache webserver after a fresh Kubuntu 14.04 install. Apache version is 2.4.7.

I usually work with files located in a separated partition (`/dev/sdb6` here), and create symbolic links into `/var/www/` folder.

The fact is it does only works with symlinks pointing to `/home/user/someFolder`, but it doesn't with folders located on the partition. This partition is `ext4`, and mounted in `media/user/partitionName`. This directory is owned by my user, and has `x` permission bits for every subfolders. The user `www-data` is assigned to my group, and my user is assigned to group `www-data`.

The `apache2.conf` file (and all eventual other vhosts conf files) have the `FollowSymLinks` option for the `<Directory /var/www/>` directive.

What do I miss ? The weird thing is that it follows the symlinks pointing to `/home/user/something`... But not the ones pointing to another location. This result in a:

```
AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/somelink
```

I even tried to add the option `-SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` to be sure it doesn't have to be the same user for the target (even if I know it's the same), but no change.

Comment: Is there any chance this partition is mounted with ACLs? Can you try `su`ing as the webserver user and accessing these files?

Comment: Something like `sudo -u www-data ls /path/to/folder` or `sudo -u www-data cat /path/to/file`.

Comment: Yes, thanks I found out. (was `sudo su - www-data -s /bin/bash`). BTW, trying to access a symlinked folder results in a `Permission denied`. And trying to access directly to the folder: the same. However, I can just access to the `/media` folder, but not its content (`/media/username/`). I found a little `+` sign at the end of the permissions: `drwxr-xr-x+`... What does it means?

Comment: Looks like you *do* have ACLs enabled: http://serverfault.com/questions/227852/what-does-a-mean-at-the-end-of-the-permissions-from-ls-l ACLs allow finer-grained control over permissions (allow/deny specific permissions to specific users/groups, NTFS permissions on Windows are the most common implementation).

Comment: Well you're right! Thanks a lot. Now I'll try to figure out how disable ACL for this partition, or [set them up](http://bencane.com/2012/05/27/acl-using-access-control-lists-on-linux/) the right way. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first hunch would be ACLs, assuming you have the POSIX permissions already set up correctly. Check if you've mounted this partition with ACLs enabled.

If you want to do some further testing, you should `su` into the webserver user (`www-data`) and run some `ls` commands to see if that works. For example, `sudo -u www-data ls /path/to/folder`.

Comment: Great. Just had to run `setfacl -b /media/parentFolder/`. More [about ACL here](http://bencane.com/2012/05/27/acl-using-access-control-lists-on-linux/). Thanks a lot!