# apache 2.4 permissions issues (forbidden)

Tags: ubuntu, symbolic-link, apache-http-server

This is driving me nuts!

Just installed Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache 2.4.7.  I've found a ton of posts on this issue but nothing seems to work.  I do have ACLs enabled, but neither -b (removing entry) or adding permissions for www-data group worked.  What's really bugging me is that I can't really tell where the problem is (I assume it is an apache issue though)?

Tried everything here: [Apache 2.4 don't follow all symlinks](https://superuser.com/questions/743716/apache-2-4-dont-follow-all-symlinks)

apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

sites-enabled/vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.net
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dev.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dev
    <Directory /var/www/dev/>
            Options +FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.dev.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.dev.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

ls -al /var/www

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   40 Sep 30 13:51 dev -> /home/yyyy/dev
```

sudo -u www-data ls -al /var/www/dev/

```
ls: cannot access /var/www/dev/: Permission denied
```

error log

```
[Tue Sep 30 14:16:22.508794 2014] [core:error] [pid 544] [client 127.0.0.1:52850] AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/dev
```

These are the auth related enabled modules (these were enabled by default during install):

```
access_compat.load -> ../mods-available/access_compat.load
auth_basic.load -> ../mods-available/auth_basic.load
authn_core.load -> ../mods-available/authn_core.load
authn_file.load -> ../mods-available/authn_file.load
authz_core.load -> ../mods-available/authz_core.load
authz_host.load -> ../mods-available/authz_host.load
authz_user.load -> ../mods-available/authz_user.load
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**SOLUTION**

I figured this out.  Hopefully my foolishness will save others some time.  I forgot I had **encrypted my home directory** which I have not done in the past.

Once I took symlink out of the equation the log error changed which led me to the issue:

```
[Tue Sep 30 16:16:36.497015 2014] [core:error] [pid 2292] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:54012] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/yyyy/zzzz') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

sure enough `drwx------ /home/yyyy/zzzz`

Comment: Tried sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www as suggested, problem persists (checked sudo -u www-data... and through the browser).  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Add `www-data` as owner and owner group:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

`root` user will always have read write permissions on whole filesystem by default.

**Or…**

You can modify the user which is running the apache but it could hurt so I don't recommend that.